# Fit one array into another regardless of sizes - Python

Tags: python, numpy, dimensions

Consider numpy arrays arr1 and arr2. They can be any number of dimensions. For example

```
arr1=np.zeros([5,8])
arr2=np.ones([4,10])
```

I would like to put arr2 into arr1 either by cutting off excess lengths in some dimensions, or filling missing length with zeros.

I have tried:

```
arr1[exec(str(",:"*len([arr1.shape]))[1:])]=arr2[exec(str(",:"*len([arr2.shape]))[1:])]
```

which is basically the same as

```
arr1[:,:]=arr2[:,:]
```

I would like to do this preferably in one line and without "for" loops.

Comment: did u try 'append' ? arr3 = [ ] arr3.append(arr1)

Comment: Forget about the one line.  Even if works it will hard to read and debug.  Spend some lines determining the shapes, whether there's need for padding, and constructing the necessary slicing.  And stay away from `exec`; it too is hard to read and debug.  `slice(a,b)` can replace `a:b` when constructing an slicing index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by coming up with the following. I used slice() as @hpaulj suggested. Considering I want to assign ph10 (an array) to ph14 (an array of zeros of size bound1):

```
ph14=np.zeros(bound1)
ph10=np.array(list1)
        
ind_min=np.min([ph14.shape,ph10.shape],0)
                           
ph24=[]
for n2 in range(0,len(ind_min.shape)):
    ph24=ph24+[slice(0,ind_min[n2])]
        
ph14[ph24]=ph10[ph24]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this :

```
arr1[:min(arr1.shape[0], arr2.shape[0]), :min(arr1.shape[1], arr2.shape[1])]=arr2[:min(arr1.shape[0], arr2.shape[0]), :min(arr1.shape[1], arr2.shape[1])]
```

without any for loop.

It's the same concept you applied in second try, but with a condition to choose minimum length.

Comment: That's true, but the arrays could have any number of dimensions.

Comment: ohh, so you want to entend for say n dimensions